# Sqlite case statement joys

Tags: sqlite, case

Ok, so here is the code that I'm trying to execute.

```
begin transaction;
SELECT [version] as ver FROM [dbinfo];
WHEN ver = 1 THEN
    UPDATE [dbinfo] SET [version]=2;
    ver = 2;
    ALTER TABLE [cards] ADD COLUMN [alternate] TEXT NOT NULL;
END
WHEN ver = 2 THEN
    UPDATE [dbinfo] SET [version]=3;
    ver = 3;
    ALTER TABLE [cards] ADD COLUMN [dependent] TEXT NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE [cards] ADD COLUMN [mutable] BOOLEAN;
END
commit transaction;
```

Doesn't work. Gets stuck on `WHEN`. I've tried also `CASE WHEN`, and a couple other various methods.
 I need to step through `ver` by `ver` with this, so any ideas on how to make something like this work for Sqlite?
Thanks.

Comment: what doesn't work? what do you expect it to do?

Comment: It's sqlite I guess? I expect it to select the current dbinfo.version, then make a change, update the dbinfo.version, then step to the next change.

Comment: I suppose in practicle terms, I'd want to end, then restart the transaction in between each `WHEN` statement, but they don't work anyways.

Comment: you need a loop to fetch the records before you work with them...

Comment: @Randy Could you provide an example? From what I figured out yesterday, the only way to really do this is to use transactions and rollbacks to simulate a type of CASE conditional statement. But if you have an alternative I'd like to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done. Have to use workarounds using transactions and stuff.